# Does Reach stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, stacking, reach

Well, I don't think I can make it any simpler then such;

- Does Reach stack?

**For example:** "Reach" weapon property, "Full Extension Fighter Utility 2", "Lunging Strike Fighter Attack 1", "Beastblooded Minotaur Path Feature 16th level", "Eternal Defender Feature 24th level", "General's Weapon" equals Reach 6?

---

**Full Extension Fighter Utility 2**

> Effect: The reach of the next melee weapon attack you
>   make before the end of your turn increases by 1.

---

**Lunging Strike Fighter Attack 1**

> *You lunge at a foe that thought it was beyond your reach.*
>   Encounter ✦ Martial, Weapon
>   **#** Standard Action **#** Melee weapon + 1 reach
>   **#** Target: One creature
>   **#** Attack: Strength – 1 vs. AC
>   **#** Hit: 2[W] + Strength modifier damage.

---

**Beastblooded Minotaur Path Features 16th level**

> **Savage Apotheosis (16th level):** Your speed
>   increases by 2 and your reach increases by 1.

---

**Eternal Defender Feature 24th level**

> **Godlike Stature (24th level):** Your size doesn’t
>   change, but your height and weight increase to 25
>   percent and 100 percent above the normal range for
>   your race, respectively. You can wield weapons as
>   if you were one size larger, and if you are normally
>   Medium or larger, your melee reach increases by 1
>   square.

---

**General's Weapon**

> **Power (Encounter):** Minor Action. **¤** Until the end of your
>   next turn, your melee reach with this weapon increases
>   by 1.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, it does stack

However, it is usually an investment that is only worth it if you can also get *threatening reach*, or pull/slide. Most of the time you can just move to an adjacent square and gain the benefits from flank as well.

You can find more on the topic in the [Wizards forum (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924041355/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3120221).

Comment: Several of the defender's reactions/interrupts (Warden) don't seem like they'd need threatening reach to be awesome.  (Or do they?)

Comment: You are right, probably Wardens gain the most from reach without threatening reach.